# Icon for menu inflater item

Tags: android

about an Android app, How can I insert an icon on a Menu inflater item? (For example this (?) on a voice called "About")
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `android:icon` attribute on the `<item>` element in your menu XML resource.